# Shooting Game Design on Proteus not Working

Tags: digital-logic, 555, counter, proteus

[image: Project Design On Proteus]

I'm designing a shooting game using 555 timer and 4017 counter. The counter should successively light up 9 LEDs, one of which is a green LED and the rest are red LEDS. When the counter reaches the green LED, the player should press the shooting button immediately. When they hit the button at the right time, a buzzer should play a tone and another green LED should light up, indicating they hit the target. I made this design in Proteus but when I run the design, only the first red LED lights up and stays lit up indefinitely when it's supposed cascade through the 9 LEDS. The image shows the running design. I failed to figure out what the root cause of this issue is, so can someone please help. I'm using a 5V power source here. Disregard the placement of the pulse generator here. It should be a button.

Comment: is the 555 timer definitely oscillating?